# Slow down animation in bar chart race python

Tags: python

I am using bar_chart_race in python to create a bar chart over 38 gameweeks. My problem is that the animation is way to quick, I'd like it to settle for each gameweek before it moves on. Is there a way to slow down the animation speed? I've tried adjusting the period_length but nothing seems to work for me. This is my code

```
bcr.bar_chart_race(df = df_tp, 
                   n_bars = 10, 
                   sort='desc',
                   period_fmt='Gameweek {x:.0f}',
                   period_length=1500,
                   title='my title',
                   filename = 'fpl.mp4'
                   )
```

Comment: Have you tried also adjusting the `steps_per_period` value in conjunction with `period length`? https://www.dexplo.org/bar_chart_race/tutorial/#change-animation-smoothness

Comment: I will post as an answer if you can please accept

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the `steps_per_period` value in conjunction with `period_length` should achieve this result as per the [docs](https://dexplo.org/bar_chart_race/tutorial/#change-animation-smoothness)

```
bcr.bar_chart_race(df, steps_per_period=20, period_length=1500)
```

Comment: It kind of works but the last gameweek is never shown and the second to last is shown very very briefly before ending

Answer (score 0):

```
bcr.bar_chart_race(df=df_tp,
               n_bars=10,
               sort='desc',
               period_fmt='Gameweek {x:.0f}',
               title='my title',
               filename='fpl.mp4',
               fps=5)  # Decrease this value to slow down the animation
```

Comment: OP has already indicated that they have tried increasing the `period_length` variable without effect

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: TypeError: bar_chart_race() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fps'

That gives me an error, fps does not seem to exist